# ROS on Ubuntu/Lubuntu 16.10

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have been trying for a while to install ros on lubuntu 16.10 and it's not working. On the official site the most recent Ubuntu version they refer to is: 14.04, does this mean that the ubuntu 16.10 is still not supported or am I not doing it right?

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255740/ros-on-ubuntu/lubuntu-16.10/) by [AL](https://answers.ros.org/users/29501/al/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-02-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[ROS REP 3](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html) for supported platforms. 16.10 support will come with the upcoming Lunar release.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The three latest [ROS distributions](http://wiki.ros.org/Distributions) nowadays (28.02.2017) are Indigo, Jade and Kinetic.

- According to [this](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu), ROS Indigo precompiled binaries are available only on Saucy (13.10) and Trusty (14.04).
- According to [this](http://wiki.ros.org/jade/Installation/Ubuntu), ROS Jade precompiled binaries are available only on Trusty (14.04), Utopic (14.10) and Vivid (15.04).
- According to [this](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu), ROS Kinetic precompiled binaries are available only on Wily (Ubuntu 15.10), Xenial (Ubuntu 16.04) and Jessie (Debian 8).

So, no 16.10 is on the list (sorry). However you could try to compile from source ([indigo instructions here](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Source), [kinetic instructions here](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Source). This however I wouldn't recommend unless you have some expertise using ROS.

The easiest thing to do would be to format your PC with 14.04 for indigo or 16.04 for kinetic, both are LTS versions being ROS Kinetic the recommended one by ROS (see [this](http://wiki.ros.org/Distributions)).

I hope this helps,

Oscar

---

Originally posted by [Oscar Lima](https://answers.ros.org/users/21475/oscar-lima/) with karma: 831 on 2017-02-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1